# Unable to delete file from Downloads folder

Tags: macos, finder, trash

I have a file (4alJRTP_.gif.part) in my downloads folder that won't seem to delete.

[image: img0]

Every time I drag it to the trash, nothing shows up in the trash and the file icon remains in the downloads folder.

I also tried opening the file and a pop-up window shows up saying "'file_name.gif.part' can't be found".

[image: img1]

How can I get rid of the file icon in my downloads folder? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you open Terminal, type `ls -aBl`, drag the file/icon into the terminal window and press enter? Then please take a screenshot of the command and the result and add it to your question.

Answer (score 2):

First of all **BE INCREDIBLY CAREFUL WHEN USING RECURSIVE DELETE FROM TERMINAL**

Next, just make sure that the applications that might have used these are closed.

That warning out of the way, here is how you can do it.

1. First open `Terminal` (in /Applications/Utilities).
2. Type `cd ~/Downloads` and press `Return`.
3. Then type `sudo srm -f` followed by a `Space` (don’t leave out the spacel). *Try this first if it doesn't work then use `sudo srm -Rf` which is the recursive form of this command*
4. **Don’t press `Return` yet.**
5. Next, in `Finder` open a window displaying the contents of the `Downloads` folder.
6. Select **ONLY** the files in that window that you want deleted and drag them into the Terminal window; *this adds the paths of all the files to the `rm`(remove) command.*
7. Now, press `Return`
8. Enter your administrator password when prompted

In a moment or two the files should be gone.

The same premise works with the Trash folder as well, with a few modifications and you may want to do this as the file may actually be there but hidden.

1. First open `Terminal` (in /Applications/Utilities).
2. Type `cd ~/.Trash` and press `Return`.
3. Then type `sudo srm -Rf` followed by a `Space` (don’t leave out the space). *You will need the recursive for to handle subdirectories, etc.*
4. **Don’t press `Return` yet.**
5. Next, click the `Trash` icon in your `Dock` to open a window displaying the contents of the `Trash`.
6. Select everything in that window and drag it into the Terminal window; this action adds the paths of all those files and folders to the `rm`(remove) command.
7. Now, press `Return`
8. Enter your administrator password when prompted

In a moment or two (depending on how much was in your Trash), the Trash icon should return to its empty state.

#### To check to see if there are hidden files you can do this.

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles true

killall Finder
```

and then to hide them again you can do:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles false

killall Finder
```

I hope that helps, and I really hope that you don't delete things you don't want to... These are powerful tools, and **With Great Power Comes Great Responsibility**.

### Update

The file that you are looking to delete, the one that says `*.part` is a file extension indicating that a file was downloaded partially.

This likely occured when Firefox, Skype, or another app able to download from the internet stopped a download mid-download.

Take a look Downloads on your browser, `command-J` on **Firefox**, `shift-command-J` on **Chrome**, and `alt-command-L` in **Safari**, and see if any of the files there has a partial download. You should be able to cancel the download there and then that file should clear up, or stop reappearing after you download it.

-- The answer I provided is based on the technique that I obtained from [Joe Kissell's article on MacWorld](http://www.macworld.com/article/2025381/mac-troubleshooting-what-to-do-when-the-trash-won-t-empty.html) and have used during the times I have not been able to empty my trash bin.

Comment: +1 for Spider Man reference. `sudo` should use that quote.

Answer (score 0):

The method may depend on how comfortable you are using Terminal…

1. Use the Terminal command `sudo rm -R` followed by the path to the stuck file, which you can easily get by dragging it into terminal after typing the command, or
2. Try [Trash It!](http://www.nonamescriptware.com) (freeware)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to 'Secure Empty Trash'?

In Finder-menu you have an option 'Secure Empty Trash' or hold `CMD` and right-click on the trash. You will get a popup allowing to 'Secure Empty Trash'